# Based on the user input, get the rank value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as below :

```
Card    Nation  Age     Category    Amount
A       India   Young   House       225
A       India   Young   Electrical  125
B       India   Young   House       250
B       India   Young   Electrical  160
B       India   Young   Bike        110
C       India   Young   Electrical  220
C       India   Young   Bike        200
C       India   Young   House       210
```

Now, i get a user input as below :

```
Nation  Age     Category    Amount
India   Young   Electrical  145
India   Young   Bike        125
India   Young   House       225
```

Now, i need to look up in the dataframe and rank the CARDs accordingly. 
In this case the Ranked Card

```
output will be 
B, C, A
```

Basically, we need to compare all the elements of the use input with all the elements in dataframe and output the Ranking order of Card values which are best match.

In our case, since `Card "A" has no Category "Bike" it comes last in our Rank`.
Other Cards have all the given Categories, so we compare the Amount .. Which ever matches the closest comes first in the Rank.

Any help ?

Comment: and what did you tried so far @learner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
temp = inp.merge(df,how='left',on=['Nation', 'Age', 'Category'])
temp['diff'] = (temp['Amount_x'] - temp['Amount_y']).abs()
temp = temp.sort_values(by=['diff'])

def get_cards(x):
    extra = {'A','B','C'}.difference(set(x))
    x=x.append(pd.Series(list(extra)))
    return ",".join(x.tolist())
temp.groupby(['Nation','Age','Category'])['Card'].apply(lambda x: get_cards(x) )
```

**Output**

```
Nation  Age    Category  
India   Young  Bike          B,C,A
               Electrical    B,A,C
               House         A,C,B
Name: Card, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here's the solution -

```
df = pd.read_csv('SO.csv', sep=' ')
user = pd.read_csv('out.csv', sep=' ')
uni = user.Category.unique()
amt = user.Amount.sum()
df_cat = df.groupby('Card')['Category'].unique()
df_sum = df.groupby('Card')['Amount'].sum()
idx_ = pd.concat([
            pd.DataFrame([3 - len(set(uni) & set(df_cat[i])) for i in range(3)], index=list('ABC'), columns=['Cat_rank']).rank(method='dense'),
            pd.DataFrame([abs(amt-df_sum[i]) for i in range(3)], index=list('ABC'), columns=['Amt_rank']).rank(method='dense')], axis=1).sum(axis=1).rank().astype(int)
idx_.reset_index().sort_values([0]).loc[:,'index'].values

# Output -> ['B', 'C', 'A']
```